# query forumaltion with multiple joins and multiple count for each table

Tags: mysql, join, count

hey guys was hoping you could help me out.

I am trying to make a query such that I have one main table with a foreign key in three different tables. Now I want to count its entries in all 3 tables seperately. This is what I have so far and hope you guys can help me fix it.

```
SELECT box_code.id, count( box_code_unused.id ) AS total, count( box_code_used.id ) AS total2, count( box_code_expired.id ) AS total3
FROM box_code
JOIN box_code_used ON box_code_used.box_code_id = box_code.id
JOIN box_code_unused ON box_code_unused.box_code_id = box_code.id
JOIN box_code_expired ON box_code_expired .box_code_id = box_code.id
GROUP BY box_code.id
```

This approach would work if I was counting entries from only one table, but since I am counting from 3 tables its incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way are the counts incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might [count distinct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) occurrences of ID:

```
SELECT box_code.id, 
       count(distinct box_code_unused.id ) AS total, 
       count(distinct box_code_used.id ) AS total2, 
       count(distinct box_code_expired.id ) AS total3
FROM box_code
LEFT JOIN box_code_used ON box_code_used.box_code_id = box_code.id
LEFT JOIN box_code_unused ON box_code_unused.box_code_id = box_code.id
LEFT JOIN box_code_expired ON box_code_expired .box_code_id = box_code.id
GROUP BY box_code.id
```

Comment: Yup that did the trick. But it wasnt exactly the distinct that fixed it, it was the left join.

Comment: @death_relic0 Oh, I see it now. IDs are distinct anyway, because these are IDs of tables themselves, not the foreign keys. Sorry about the oversight.

Answer (score 1):

Use the subqueries like this:

```
SELECT box_code.id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM box_code_used b1 WHERE b1.box_code_id = box_code.id) AS total1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM box_code_unused b2 WHERE b2.box_code_id = box_code.id) AS total2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM box_code_expired b3 WHERE b3.box_code_id = box_code.id) AS total3
FROM box_code
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use right join. that way it will include records not available in one table but available in other.